# How can I find the location of the source code for an app running on an Ubuntu image?

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, process

Let's say I've logged into an image that was spun up by an automated process and it's serving up a website (in my case it's a Rails site). I'm rooted, but don't know where to find the source code. Given that there are processes running that are serving the code, or at least a compiled version of it, is there a reliable way to figure out where on the instance the source code lives?

Answer (score 0):

Note a file the web server use and find it.

In exemple;

**find / -name "index.html"**

It happened to me in the past as I'am more windows than linux. (I created a cloud linux VM to make a webserver to learn and I didnt knew where the home folder was to the webserver service)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ss -tp` to list all open ports with their process ids. Use `ps aux | grep PID` to display the command executed.